# Angular.js templates not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular.js and just trying to get my head around the basics and hopefully this is something simple, but I am having trouble loading in a templateUrl.

My index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <h1>Introduction to Angular.JS</h1>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>



  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js is:

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
            })
    }])
```

My home.html is: `<h1>home template</h1>`

So I dont know why this isn't working, but the error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/code/Desktop/angular/templates/home.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Thanks in advance, Gab

Answer (score 0):

This error comes due to a security restriction put by the browser. You can try below steps:

- Try to run your code in some other browsers
- Add the templates inside `index.html` itself by placing the content inside `script` tag. These script elememts should appear after `ng-app`. ([ref link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache))

  `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    Content of the template goes here
  </script>`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you use `<ng-view> </ng-view>` for loading your templates. and second is use `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">` for you each partial view. third thing is not mandatory but use otherwise at last that makes sense. Here is fiddle for you check it out 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a41rjj8/)

Comment: He is using uiRouter. He must use <ui-view>, not <ng-view>.

Comment: The question is about state provider, not routeProvider. You have answered something entirely not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your page locally, I suggest you install a http-server and run it in there ...
Then you avoid CORS issues like that

Example:
with node.js installed

## `cd ~/myProjectFolder`

## `npm i http-server`

## `http-server ./`

Then you could also just enter `localhost:8080` in your browser and wouldn't have to point it to some URI/folder